# "Modules" in Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, repository-pattern

We're using a Repository Pattern in our latest project. But we have find some difficulties implementing a "module" to that architeture.

In the below image, you can see how the main solution is tiered and how the "module" is tiered.
[image]

What we wanted to do is having the module without the responsability of the data access/handling. 
That's why we dont have the Repository Pattern there.

Oh, and we are using NHibernate so we are expecting that saving our module in the main bussiness tier will respect the chain of relationship defined in the Modelo Tier in the "module".

Comment: Please don't add things like " [C#] [VS2010]" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: What question, exactly, are you asking here?

Comment: I'm sorry, for the tags thing. The question is, how can I, using NHibernate, not use a Repository in the module, leaving the responsability of data handling only in one "generic" sets of data handling (ex.: insert, list, getbyid) in the main solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following page http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

The author gives a brief explanation about the repository pattern and how he used it on Nhibernate with linq, but you could also use HQL ...

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "repository pattern nhibernate" you'll find a wealth of articles demonstrating the technique.

However, I think it's important to ask as to whether you need to abstract NHibernate any further. In essence, NHibernate can be your repository.

http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer